# how to add values to dictionary in a loop without using array

Tags: python, json

i would like to re-structure the dictionary `geographical information` so that when i display its contents i get the results without the index number.for more clarity, as shown in the screen shot below, i want to be able to
display the contents of the aforementioned dictionary without showing the indeces of the array circled in red.
i know it is due to the usage of the array `['data']` but is there any way to restructure the dictionary so that i get the data displayed without having those indices?? it will be easier for my calculations

**code**

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    coverageDataForT['data'].append ({
        "areaOfCoverage" :(arr[i]/(arr2[i])) *100,
    })
```

**dict**:

```
 "geographical information": {
        "coverageDataForTreatment": {
            "coverageDataForT":coverageDataForT['data],
        }
        ..
        ..
    }
```

**image**:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

**code**

```
coverageDataForTreatment = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        coverageDataForTreatment.append((arr1[i]/(arr2[i])) *100)
```

**dict**:

```
"geographical information": {
        "treatment": {
            "coverageDataForTreatment":coverageDataForTreatment,
            ....
            ....
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The indices will always be there because that's how `console.log` displays an Array. What you need is to get rid of the object inside each array element so that you don't have to expand each one.

One way to do it without affecting the array itself and getting the representation in a useful format would be to `reduce` it to a string:

```
let output = arr.reduce((accumulator, current, index) => {
  let expressionResult = (arr[index]/(arr2[index])) *100;
  accumulator += `${expressionResult} \n`.
}, '');
console.log(output); // will log each value in a separate line in the console.
```

Comment: i think there is no console.log in python

Comment: lol for some reason I had assumed it was javascript! my bad!